# How to create this layout in WPF (3 controls)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, layout

[image]

I made this image that shows the controls. The top one is a `ListView` and the others are `ListView` controls as well with additional controls.

But I can't figure out how to layout them to look like that.

Currently I use 3 `DockPanels` for each `ListView` where the top one uses Top `VerticalAlignment`, the others use Bottom for `VerticalAlignment`, Left and Right (for `HorizontalAlignment`).

But when I look at it, the other 2 controls appear after the top `ListView` to its right side. I can see this when I scale the top `DockPanel` to half the size, then the other 2 DockPanels show up, attached to the top DockPanel's right side.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: That's some weird layout you got there...

Comment: Yes, it's a different app, but the layout actually fits. Think of it like an options Editor-like sort of window :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

The grid has no fixed widths or heights and should accommodate whatever controls you add.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="Aqua" Height="100"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Background="Orange" Height="100" Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Background="Green" Height="60" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
```

Initial window

[image]

Resized window

[image]

EDIT in response to comment

If you want a progressbar in the top panel, just use:

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
       Background="Aqua" Orientation="Vertical">
        <ListView Height="50" Background="Purple"></ListView>
        <ProgressBar Height="20" IsIndeterminate="True" ></ProgressBar>
    </StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. One thing I couldn't do is this: Basically in the first stackpanel one with the Aqua color, I have 2 controls, progressbar and the listview. I set the listview's width to auto and it fill the window's width, but the same doesn't work for the progress bar which looks like less than 10 pixel in width. I have to manually set the width, but I don't want this and the window scaling should scale it to the window size anyway. Any ideas? Not sure if they are related.

Comment: I was using HorizontalAlignment="Center" that made it small, after seeing your edit, realized it. Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need them to be DockPanels, or this is a fixed layout?

If it's fixed you could do something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="80"></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Name="dockPanel1" Background="CadetBlue">
    </ListView>
    <ListView Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Name="dockPanel2" Background="Cyan">
    </ListView>
    <ListView Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="2" Name="dockPanel3" Background="DarkRed">
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
```

I made the area between your three panels re-sizable as your window resizes.

Instead of the listviews that I used, you can put pretty much anything, a user control, another grid, whatever.

The colors will show you where the listview sections are easily.

You will probably want to adjust the sizes, or change the resize behavior.

You can learn more about grids [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html)

Comment: Thanks, I used dock panels because I was trying to anchor the controls to sides namely top center, bottom left and bottom right. I didn't want to hard code controls. Is yours fixed? Because I don't see hard coded coordinates.

Comment: Yes it is fixed. You don't need coordinates because the grid behavior is supposed to take care of that for you. The size and position of the control in the bottom left corner for instance is controlled by the behavior of that particular grid rectangle. So in my case, it is taking the 2 bottom rows, and 1 column. I hard-coded the sizes of the rows, and the columns, so the control will always be 50+50 x 100. However, if you set the size of the row or column to "Auto", then the the grid will adjust to the size that the containing control wants.  I think if you play with this you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is the sort of scenario [Alignment, Margins, and Padding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx) are made to handle...

Comment: Thanks but can I do this kind of irregular layouts with grids?

Comment: The example I linked actually is using Panels. Children of a Grid will be sized to fill their cells - pardon the oversight! :)

Comment: Thanks but the example seems to use StackPanel, are you sure it's gonna allow me controls that aren't exactly on top of each other? Basically controls #2 and #3.

Comment: I saw that but will this actually snap the controls to the sides of the window so when the window is resized, everything will act correctly similar to using anchors in winforms?

Comment: I don't know offhand (get ye to a sample WPF App project and try it :)), but if the StackPanel is set to size with your window, and the elements are set to align with opposite sides of the StackPanel, they *should* "stick" to those sides...